# What moves can Smeargle not Sketch?

Tags: pokemon-series

Smeargle gets the special move Sketch, which allows him to copy any mover permanently. I  plan on "sketching" out some plans for Smeargles (see what I did there), and I want to know which moves are a no-go, if any.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply [anything but Chatter and Struggle as Bulbapedia states](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Smeargle_(Pok%C3%A9mon)). You also can't Sketch Sketch I think. Struggle isn't really intended to be a "move", and Chatter is a [Chatot exclusive](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Chatter_(move)), and highly unusual, move.

> Chatter is the one of only three moves that cannot be Sketched, presumably because as a field move, if used by a Pokémon other than Chatot, it does not temporarily change the battle cry of the respective Pokémon to the recorded version even if audio is recorded. This is because recording audio via Chatter activates a Pokémon's alternative cry, where Chatot's alternative cry exclusively depends on what was recorded when the Chatter field move is used; however, Chatter still remains not Sketchable even in Generation VI, where vocals cannot be recorded.

Comment: Transform can be sketched?

Comment: @scenia as of gen 6 yes, the banlist has altered slightly over generations

Comment: Wow, that's cool. So smeargle really can become a somewhat more versatile Ditto.

Comment: @scenia I suppose that's a thought; a bit better health than Ditto too, though an Imposter Ditto is probably preferred for most situations

Comment: @Benbrocka, but if given a 1 or 2 turn lead, the Smeargle can set up, then transform, which could make some devastating combos.

Comment: @ShadowZ. the only "setup" you can make are entry hazards or cast negative status moves, because Transform copies each enemy stats, ignoring your stats modifications.

Answer (score -2):

well from doing field research with my trainer I can sketch any move except Struggle. chatter I don't know yet since he has yet to get a Chatot. but I am able to Sketch Transform (though it takes a bit of practice for timing on use.) I also Sketched both Baneful Bunker (Toxapex exclusive move) and Happy Hour (Munchlax exclusive move). so the pokemon Exclusive rule does not apply to Sketch.

Comment: Happy Hour is not munchlax exclusive. It is event-exclusive.